# Iteratively filter a dataframe and create multiple filtered dataframes as result

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id,    ~list,
    1,  "apple",
    1,   "pear",
    1, "banana",
    2,  "apple",
    2, "banana",
    3,  "apple"
  )
```

I want create a list of the unique elements of the column df$list

```
unique(df$list)
unique_list <- c("apple", "pear", "banana")
```

I want to iterate over the main df over the each value of `unique_list` and filter the whole df and create 3 different dataframe as a results, named `df_`"each element of the list".

I can do it for individual elements like this:

```
df %>% filter(list = 'apple') -> df_apple

# and:
df %>% filter(list = 'pear') -> df_pear

# and so on...
```

So eventually I´ll have 3 filtered dataframe, `df_apple`, `df_pear`, `df_apple`.

How can I make this process more concise?

Comment: With `split(df, df$list)` you'll get list of 3 dataframes.

Comment: or, if you want to remain in the tidy bubble, `tidyr::nest(df, list)$data`